# Error response client_not_active when trying to obtain access token using curl

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, nest-api

I'm going step-by-step [Nest REST Quick Guide](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/rest-quick-guide) and now blocked with error response during attempts to obtain an access token.
Response is:

```
{"error":"client_not_active","error_description":"client is not active","instance_id":"here_is_something_looks_like_guid"}
```

I've checked [Error Messages Guide](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/authorization-reference/), and it helps me a lot to understand that "Client not active". Useful, huh? 
So which client and how to activate it?
I have a home simulator working, also I've registered a so-called 'product', which I want to develop (so I have Product ID, Product Secret, Authorization URL and Access Token URL).

**[Upd]**
For all operations I've used curl.
However with Firefox addon which sends POST data I'm able to obtain the access_token. So I keep the question, but so far will stick to browser.

Answer (score 1):

This means the your product/client has been deactivated, most likely due to a violation of the Terms of Service. Is the problem consistently occurring?

Comment: See update to question - it returns "client_not_active" only if I try to obtain a token with curl, but it works if I do that with Firefox and post request.

Comment: If it works with Firefox, then there is most likely something wrong with the curl command. Make sure that you are using the correct Product ID, a.k.a. Client ID, and Product Secret, a.k.a. Client Secret.